# Определение типа элемента в массиве String

Tags: java

Есть массив:

```
String[][] a = new String[][]{{"55", "java", "40"}, {"ex", "5", "100"};
```

Не могу сообразить как в цикле определить какой элемент является числом, а какой нет. 
Т.е. к примеру у меня есть задача: посчитать все элементы массива которые являются числом, а у меня естественно каждый раз доходя до `back` вылетает в ошибку `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: только где вы тут нашли `back` ?)

Comment: виноват не back - java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1(медленный)**:

Обрабатывать исключение и просто не суммировать в случае ошибки.

```
int sum = 0;
...
try {
    sum += Integer.parseInt( input );
}
catch( Exception e ) {
}
```

**Вариант 2(написать свою функцию проверки строки на число):**

```
public static boolean isInteger(String str) {
     if (str == null) {
        return false;
    }
    int length = str.length();
    if (length == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    int i = 0;
    if (str.charAt(0) == '-') {
        if (length == 1) {
            return false;
        }
        i = 1;
    }
    for (; i < length; i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (c < '0' || c > '9') {
             return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

и вызывать эту функцию перед каждым числом. На больших объемах данных такой подход может дать прирост в пару десятков раз.

Ответ основан на [ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237159/whats-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-string-represents-an-integer-in-java) с английского SO